# Call C++ library from main.mm results in compile error - verify declaration conflicts with macro

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, objective-c++, berkeley-db

I have the following code in a header included in main.mm:

```
1.  virtual int truncate(DbTxn *, u_int32_t *, u_int32_t);
2.  virtual int upgrade(const char *name, u_int32_t flags);
3.  virtual int verify(
4.      const char *, const char *, __DB_STD(ostream) *, u_int32_t);
```

The first two lines are for context and to show what is working.  The third and fourth lines have the following errors:

> Macro "verify" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 1
>
> 'verify' declared as a 'virtual' field

If I add a random character to the end of the verify declaration like `verityx` then the file compiles without a problem.  Is `verify` reserved?

Edit:
My main.mm file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "db_cxx.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    return 0;
}
```

Edit 2:

The only two uses of the word "verify" in the berkeley header are:

```
virtual int log_verify(DB_LOG_VERIFY_CONFIG *);

virtual int verify(
    const char *, const char *, __DB_STD(ostream) *, u_int32_t);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Macro "verify" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 1
```

means that there's a `#define verify(x) ...` somewhere. It's not reserved in C++ but something you're including is defining it.

A quick

```
fgrep -r verify /usr/include | fgrep '#define'
```

yields, amongst a lot of other things,

```
/usr/include/AssertMacros.h:        #define verify(assertion) __Verify(assertion)
```

After you've included all the OS X/iOS headers you need, it should be safe to `#undef verify` before including bdb.

Comment: Maybe in the berkeley-db header?

Comment: I checked that too.  Posted all two instances of it in the header.  :-(

Comment: Sorry. Didn't understand the nuances of the issue. Your edit helped. See the updated answer.

Comment: I just found AssertMacros.h myself, but had no clue how to resolve the issue.  Thanks!